# Writing Excel Spreadsheet in Perl

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet

I'm working on writing an excel spreadsheet from a Perl script and need to set the row height of specific rows to "0" if no data exists.  Here is some of what I have written so far.  It works on writing data based on the text file, but if the item is not in the text file then it leaves an empty row which I want to eliminate.  Any help is appreciated.

```
my $file = 'forecast.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line =<$fh>) {
  if (index($line, 'M1501235') != -1) {

  $worksheet->write(11,0, "M1501", $print2);
  $worksheet->write(11,1, "FUND TO FUND TRANSFERS", $print);
  $worksheet->write(11,2, "DES", $print);
  $worksheet->write(11,3, "0001", $print);
  $worksheet->write(11,4, "", $print);
  $worksheet->write(11,5, "NA", $print);
  $worksheet->write(11,6, "SEE RH", $print);
  }
#  else $worksheet->set_row (11, 0);
  if (index($line, 'M2201235') != -1) {
  $worksheet->write(12,0, "M2201", $print2);
  $worksheet->write(12,1, "BPS FUND BALANCE ERROR RPT", $print);
  $worksheet->write(12,2, "L&I", $print);
  $worksheet->write(12,3, "0010", $print);
  $worksheet->write(12,4, "", $print);
  $worksheet->write(12,5, "NA", $print);
  $worksheet->write(12,6, "2 COPIES 37", $print);
  }
  else $worksheet->set_row ($_, 0) for (0..11);

elsif (index($line, 'M2301235') != -1) {
  $worksheet->write(13,0, "M2201", $print2);
  $worksheet->write(13,1, "BPS/ARC RECOCILIATION RPT/BPS CREDIT BALANCE RPT", $print);
  $worksheet->write(13,2, "L&I", $print);
  $worksheet->write(13,3, "0010", $print);
  $worksheet->write(13,4, "", $print);
  $worksheet->write(13,5, "NA", $print);
  $worksheet->write(13,6, "2 COPIES 37", $print);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using?  Is it Excel::Writer::XLSX?

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to set the row to hidden instead of 0.

[set_row](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#set_row-row-height-format-hidden-level-collapsed) has the following arguments:

```
set_row( $row, $height, $format, $hidden, $level, $collapsed )
```

The fourth argument is a flag that toggles the visibility of the row.  Any arguments that you don't want to explicitly set can be passed in as `undef`

This means, you can change

```
$worksheet->set_row ($_, 0) for (0..11);
```

to

```
$worksheet->set_row ($_, undef,undef,1) for (0..11);
```

`set_row` works the same for `Excel::Writer::XLSX` and `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`.